# Using Groovy to send Soap envelope

Tags: soap, groovy

Is there any way to send a Soap envelope using Groovy

Answer (score 3):

Groovy has `groovyws` for webservices. Take a look at the wiki page: http://groovy.codehaus.org/GroovyWS

Comment: Rha, you were faster than I could be ! GroovyWS is the faster way to develop web-service client, but also the slower to execute them :-) However I find it incredibly convenient.

Comment: I tried to use it with exchange 2010 and failed miserably, mostly due to crazy exchange-requirements. I ended up generating my own soap requests and sending them with the httpbuilder, but since this is just for a one-time mega-import this is ok ;)